# API deployment for mobile applications

Tags: android, mysql, spring-boot, deployment, cloud-foundry

I'm working on Android project connected via retrofit to spring-boot API deployed on my local machine. API is connected to MySQL database. Now, I need my API make accessible from external network so I'm looking good place to deploy my back-end.
I heard about Heroku, Pivotal, AWS, but all of them looks expensive. Are better alternative for api deployment?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

1. Have a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
2. A [small guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-cloud-backend-for-your-android-app-using-firebase/) about setup.
3. [Guide on building Android Apps on Firebase and Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible).